# Spring web flow: How to return an Event object with custom attributes and then access it in flow.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, web-deployment

Here's a snippet that gets called from Spring action state.

```
public Event doSomething(){

    /* do something */

    // (1) How to create a instance of this and set custom attributes?
    AttributeMap customAttributeMap; 

    Event done = new Event(this, "done", customAttributeMap);

}
```

Here's a snippet from flow.xml that invokes about method:

```
<action-state id="someStateId">
    <evaluate expression="flowAction.doSomething" />
    <transition on="done">
            <!-- (2) How do I access my custom attribute set in Event -->
        <evaluate expression="currentEvent.attributes.pageName" result="requestScope.pageName" />
    </transition>
</action-state>
```

So, my questions are:

1. How to create an Event with custom attributes set?
2. How to access this event's custom attributes in the spring flow xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LocalAttributeMap. The flow would be something like this:

```
<action-state id="action1">
   <evaluate expression="myFirstController.setAttribute()"/>
   <transition on="done" to="action2"/>
</action-state>

<action-state id="action2">
   <evaluate expression="mySecondController.getAttribute(flowRequestContext.currentEvent.attributes)"/>
   <transition on="done" to="myView"/>
</action-state>
```

The method setAttribute of the first controller sets the attribute map:

```
public Event setAttribute() {
   Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
   map.put("testAttribute", "test");
   AttributeMap attributeMap = new LocalAttributeMap(map);
   return new Event(this, "done", attributeMap);
}
```

And then you could get the attribute value at the other controller:

```
public Event getAttribute(AttributeMap attributeMap) {
   String value = attributeMap.getString("testAttribute");
   ...
}
```

Regards.